# How to Chunk Data into Multiple Dictionaries in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape an HTML document of radio stations and meta information. The HTML was generated from a PDF, so the code isn't formatted very beautifully:

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="stl_02">
        
        <div class="stl_03">
            <object data="example.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="stl_04" style="position:relative; width:0; height:0;">
                <embed src="example.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
            </object>
        </div>
        <div class="stl_view">
            <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 6.3363em; "><span class="stl_31 stl_08 stl_57" style="font-weight:bold; word-spacing:0.0082em;">All Genres &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 10.7789em; "><span class="stl_58 stl_08 stl_59" style="word-spacing:-0.0015em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.  &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 12.1244em; "><span class="stl_58 stl_08 stl_42" style="word-spacing:-0.0022em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.  &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 13.4642em; "><span class="stl_58 stl_08 stl_53" style="word-spacing:-0.001em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. </span><span class="stl_58 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.248em;">&nbsp;</span><span class="stl_58 stl_08 stl_50" style="word-spacing:-0.0025em;">Lorem ipsum &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 14.8039em; "><span class="stl_58 stl_08 stl_42" style="word-spacing:-0.0021em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.  &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 16.1495em; "><span class="stl_58 stl_08 stl_42" style="word-spacing:-0.0016em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.  &nbsp;</span></div>
                
                
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 18.5129em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_61" style="word-spacing:-0.0052em;">Radio Station 1 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 19.5633em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 20.6171em; "><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">http://www.google.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 21.7671em; "><a href="mailto:contact@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_39">contact@gmail.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 22.9171em; "><a href="mailto:info@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">info@gmail.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 24.0671em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.   &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 25.2171em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:-0.0001em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.   &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 26.3671em; "><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://www.facebook.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 27.5171em; "><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_22">https://twitter.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 28.6671em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                
                
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 30.8729em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_64">Radio Station 2 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 31.9233em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 32.9821em; "><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://www.google.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 34.1321em; "><a href="mailto:info@google.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">info@google.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 35.2821em; "><a href="https://radiostations2.co/submissions/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://radiostations2.co/submissions/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 36.4321em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_37" style="word-spacing:0.0003em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 37.5821em; "><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">https://www.facebook.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 38.7321em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 39.8821em; "><a href="https://soundcloud.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_22">https://soundcloud.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 41.0321em; "><a href="https://open.spotify.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://open.spotify.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>


                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 43.2333em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_53" style="word-spacing:0.0005em;">Radio Station 3 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 44.2838em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 45.3421em; "><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://www.google.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 46.4921em; "><a href="mailto:contact@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">contact@gmail.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 47.6421em; "><a href="http://radiostation3.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_22">http://radiostation3.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 48.7921em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_37" style="word-spacing:0.0016em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.&nbsp;</span></div>
                
                
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 50.9979em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_59" style="word-spacing:-0.002em;">Radio Station 4 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 52.0483em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 53.1021em; "><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://www.google.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 54.2521em; "><a href="mailto:contact@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">contact@gmail.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 55.4021em; "><a href="http://radiostation4.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">http://radiostation4.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 56.5521em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 57.7021em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_36" style="word-spacing:-0.0005em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 58.8521em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_22" style="word-spacing:0.0004em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div id="11_0" style="position:absolute;left:-0.1667em;top:-12.8333em;">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- ./stl_view -->
    </div> <!-- ./stl_02 -->


    
    <div class="stl_02">
        <div class="stl_03">
            <object data="example.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="stl_04" style="position:relative; width:0; height:0;">
                <embed src="example.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
            </object>
        </div>
        <div class="stl_view">
            <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 7.1383em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:-0.0006em;">Radio Station 5 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 8.1887em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 9.2421em; "><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">https://www.google.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 10.3921em; "><a href="mailto:contact@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">contact@gmail.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 11.5421em; "><a href="http://radiostation5.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">http://radiostation5.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 12.6921em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_20" style="word-spacing:-0.0014em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.  &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 13.8421em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_36" style="word-spacing:-0.0004em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 14.9921em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_20" style="word-spacing:0.0001em;">Lorem ipsum dolor. &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 16.1421em; "><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://www.facebook.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 17.2921em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 18.4421em; "><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://twitter.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 19.5921em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_36">Canada &nbsp;</span></div>


                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 21.7983em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_20" style="word-spacing:0.0017em;">Radio Station 6 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 22.8488em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 23.9071em; "><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://www.google.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 25.0571em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_43">Joh</span><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_65">n</span><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_66">D</span><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_42">oe &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 26.2071em; "><a href="mailto:john@radiostation6.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">john@radiostation6.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 27.3571em; "><a href="http://www.radiostation6.com/contacts.html" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">http://www.radiostation6.com/contacts.html &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 28.5071em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_37" style="word-spacing:0.0009em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. &nbsp;</span></div>


                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 30.7083em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_43" style="word-spacing:0.0024em;">Radio Station 7 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 31.7588em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 32.8171em; "><a href="http://radiostation7.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">http://radiostation7.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 33.9671em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_22" style="word-spacing:0.0026em;">Submissions: </span><a href="mailto:contact@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">contact@gmail.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                
                
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 36.1733em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:-0.0021em;">Radio Station 8 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 37.2238em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 38.2771em; "><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://www.google.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 39.4271em; "><a href="mailto:john@radiostation8.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">john@radiostation8.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 40.5771em; "><a href="mailto:feedback@radiostation8.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">feedback@radiostation8.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 41.7271em; "><a href="http://radiostation8.com/premiere-submissions/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">http://radiostation8.com/premiere-submissions/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 42.8771em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.0001em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 44.0271em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_36" style="word-spacing:-0.0005em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 45.1771em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_36" style="word-spacing:-0.0013em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 46.3271em; "><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://www.facebook.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 47.4771em; "><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://twitter.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 48.6271em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>



                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 50.8329em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_42" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Radio Station 9 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 51.8833em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 52.9421em; "><a href="http://radiostation9.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_09">http://radiostation9.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 54.0921em; "><a href="mailto:contact@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">contact@gmail.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 55.2421em; "><a href="http://radiostation9.com/about-2/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">http://radiostation9.com/about-2/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 56.3921em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_44" style="word-spacing:0.0016em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 57.5421em; "><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">https://www.facebook.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 58.6921em; "><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://twitter.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- ./ stl_view -->
    </div> <!-- ./ stl_02 -->



    <div class="stl_02">
        <div class="stl_03">
            <object data="example.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="stl_04" style="position:relative; width:0; height:0;">
                <embed src="example.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
            </object>
        </div>
        <div class="stl_view">
            <div class="stl_05 stl_06">
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 6.0821em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 7.2321em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_44" style="word-spacing:0.0006em;">San Francisco, CA, US &nbsp;</span></div>


                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6.0009em;top: 9.4379em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_41" style="word-spacing:0.003em;">Radio Station 10 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6.0009em;top: 10.4883em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 11.5421em; "><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">https://www.google.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 12.6921em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_39" style="word-spacing:-0.0006em;">John Doe &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 13.8421em; "><a href="mailto:john@radiostation10.com " target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_39">john@radiostation10.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 14.9921em; "><a href="http://radiostation10.com/about_me/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">http://radiostation10.com/about_me/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 16.1421em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_44" style="word-spacing:0.0013em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.  &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 17.2921em; "><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://www.facebook.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 18.4421em; "><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://twitter.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 19.5921em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 20.7421em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0em;">Canada, Toronto &nbsp;</span></div>


                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 22.9479em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_45" style="word-spacing:0.0006em;">Radio Station 11 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 23.9983em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 25.0571em; "><a href="http://www.radiostation11.org/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">http://www.radiostation11.org/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 26.2071em; "><a href="mailto:info@radiostation11.org" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">info@radiostation11.org &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 27.3571em; "><a href="http://www.radiostation11.org/contact.php" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">http://www.radiostation11.org/contact.php &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 28.5071em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_36" style="word-spacing:-0.0001em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl. &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 29.6571em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 30.8071em; "><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_14">https://twitter.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 31.9571em; "><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://www.facebook.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 33.1071em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_22" style="word-spacing:-0.0045em;">Milwaukee, WI &nbsp;</span></div>



                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6.0009em;top: 35.3083em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_41">Radio Station 12 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6.0009em;top: 36.3588em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 37.4171em; "><a href="http://radiostation12.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">http://radiostation12.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 38.5671em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_22">John Doe &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 39.7171em; "><a href="mailto:radiostation12@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_20">radiostation12@gmail.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 40.8671em; "><a href="https://radiostation12.com/submissions/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://radiostation12.com/submissions/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 42.0171em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_41" style="word-spacing:-0.0016em;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor volutpat nisl.  &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 43.1671em; "><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://www.facebook.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 44.3171em; "><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://twitter.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 45.4671em; "><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://www.instagram.com/ &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                
                
                
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 48.8229em; "><span class="stl_60 stl_08 stl_59" style="word-spacing:-0.0021em;">Radio Station 13 &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 49.8678em; "><span class="stl_62 stl_08 stl_52" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Genre: All/Various &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 50.9271em; "><a href="https://radiostation13.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">https://radiostation13.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 52.0771em; "><a href="mailto:rosvot@rosvot.fi" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">rosvot@rosvot.fi &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 53.2271em; "><a href="https://radiostation13.com/info" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_36">https://radiostation13.com/info &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 54.3771em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_14" style="word-spacing:0.0005em;">Contact: John Doe, Jane Doe, Keith Doe &nbsp;</span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 55.5271em; "><a href="mailto:contact@radiostation13.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_37">contact@radiostation13.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 56.6771em; "><a href="mailto:info@radiostation13.com" target="_blank"><span class="stl_63 stl_08 stl_22">info@radiostation13.com &nbsp;</span></a></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:6em;top: 57.8271em; "><span class="stl_35 stl_08 stl_20" style="word-spacing:0.0002em;">Lorem ipsum dolor &nbsp;</span></div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- ./ stl_view -->
    </div> <!-- ./ stl_02 -->
</body>
```

Here is the code for my latest attempt. The issues that I've experienced are as follows:

1. Some of the genres do no match their respective radio stations.
2. The code appears to only select every other radio station

```py
radio_station_count     = 0

# Find All Chunks of Data
for chunk1 in soup.find_all("div", class_="stl_02"):

    # Loop Through Each .stl_view > .stl_05.stl_06 | New Soup Object??
    for chunk2 in chunk1.select("div.stl_view > div.stl_05.stl_06"):

        # Extract data from elements/text within .stl_01
        for chunk3 in chunk2.find_all("div", class_="stl_01"):

            # Extract all <span> and <a> tag direct children
            for data in chunk3.find_all(["span","a"], recursive=False):

                # Determine type of data
                data_type   = get_data_type(data)
                
                # Get data
                item = data.get_text()
                # Sanitize Data ...
                item = item.replace("&nbsp;", "")

                # TODO: Add Data to appropriate variable for CSV line ( i.e. category_state ) ...
                if data_type    == 'radio_station':
                    if radio_station_count > 0:
                        # Start a new line in the CSV ...

                        # Prepare dictionary for radio station data ...
                        radioStationBlock = {
                            "category_state": category_state,
                            "radio_station_name": radio_station_name,
                            "genre": genre,
                            "website": website,
                            "emails": emails,
                            "description": description,
                            "facebook": facebook,
                            "twitter": twitter,
                            "instagram": instagram,
                            "soundcloud": soundcloud,
                            "spotify": spotify,
                            "location": location,
                            "misc_links": misc_links,
                            "misc_text": misc_text
                        }

                        
                        # Add radio station block to radio station dictionary ...
                        radioStationList["radioStations"].append([radioStationBlock])
                        radio_station_count = 0

                    
                    else:
                        # Do something
                        radio_station_count += 1

                    # Update Radio Station Name Variable
                    radio_station_name   = item

                elif data_type    == 'genre':
                    genre   = item
                    # Do something
```

Using BeautifulSoup, what is most efficient way to loop through the HTML & chunk the data into multiple lists beginning with the Radio Station Name?

For Example - [
'Radio Station Name',
'Genre',
'Website',
'E-mail(s)',
'Description',
'Facebook',
'Twitter',
'Instagram',
'SoundCloud',
'Spotify',
'Location',
'Misc Link(s)',
'Misc Text' ]
)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far. Also, the expected output isn't so clear what you want. Can you show the expected output with using the HTML you provided

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will update my question accordingly

Comment: `[x.text.strip() for x in soup.select(".stl_08")]`, no? Pretty much any selector will work here based on what's shown.

Comment: Please note: get_data_type() is a custom method that I wrote. It's essentially an if/elif block that returns a string based on the classes of a given element